# Group by and Order by mysql than show the latest post

Tags: php, mysql

after searching i can find a answer. this is my problem
This is what i tried to do but not showing the newest posts in results

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM berichten where ontvanger = '$session->username' 
GROUP BY fromm ORDER BY date DESC");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
echo $row['fromm'];
echo $row['msg'];
echo $Row['date'];
}
```

i want to group table fromm and when i do this i want show the latest post of table fromm but its showing the old post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    berichten a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  fromm, MAX(Date) Date
            FROM    berichten
            GROUP   BY fromm
        ) b ON a.fromm = b.fromm AND
                a.date = b.date
WHERE   a.ontvanger = '$session->username'
```

and can also be written as

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    berichten a
WHERE   a.Date = 
        (
            SELECT  MAX(Date)
            FROM    berichten b
            WHERE   a.fromm = b.fromm
        ) AND
        a.ontvanger = '$session->username'
```